# How to download csv using jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I am using following piece of code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fireDownload(){
    var path= '<?php echo URL; ?>/downloadmyfile';
    $.post(path,function(data){
   alert(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

I have the downloadfileAction in my controller

```
public function downloadmyfileAction()
    {
                $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
                $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
                  .....       .....         ....
        $this->view->List=$myData; 
                ///CREATE CSV
                $myFile = "ORDER_" . time() . ".csv";
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$myFile\"");
                header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-16LE");
                $out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
                $csvData = array('SlNo', 'Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4','Test5');
                $o = fputcsv($out, $csvData, ',', '"');
                $count = 1;
                foreach($myData as $key => $value)
                {
                $csvData = array();
                $csvData = array($count,$value['Test1'],$value['Test2'],$value['Test3'],$value['Test4'],$value['Test5']);
                $o = fputcsv($out, $csvData, ',', '"');
                $count++;
                }

                fclose($fh);

                // DOWNLOAD CSV
                echo $out;
                die();

    }
```

When i fire the function downloadmyfile, it will generate alert with unknown language,language seems japan. I am not able to download the file using `jquery post` method. Kindly help me

Comment: $csvData = array('SlNo', 'Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4,'Test5'); missing an apostrophe after 'Test4

Comment: var path= '<?php echo URL; ?>/downloadmyfile'; isn't Url supposed to be $URL? Maybe...

Comment: @benhowdle89 No Mr.Ben That is the constant variable , I defined in bootstrap file

Comment: What happens if you open your '<?php echo URL; ?>/downloadmyfile' file directly in the browser? Does it produce correct results?

Comment: Yes When i hit directly i got the file with SAVE Option

Comment: I got alert with some unknown format "汓潎∬牏敤⁲∣唬敳湲浡ⱥ伢摲牥䐠瑡≥∬桃湡........"

Answer (score 0):

your download should be something like this:

```
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $this->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('Content-Type', $contentType)
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="'.$filename . '";')
        ->setBody($data);
```

Where $data is the contents of your file, in your case csv data. $contentType would be some content type, in your case "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-16LE". And finally $filename would be the filename that appears when you start downloading, in your case that would be: "ORDER_".time().".csv". Don't use die() and don't use echo. When you call your controller the download starts automatically.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Now I got alert with exact data but i am not able to download the file

Comment: When i remove echo and die, again i got alert message like "汓潎∬牏敤⁲∣唬敳湲浡ⱥ伢摲牥䐠...."

Answer (score 0):

finally i found by using ,

```
function firedownload(){ 
    document.fname.action='<?php echo ADMIN_URL; ?>/downloadmyfile';
    document.fname.submit();
}
```

Also Changed line in `downloadmyfileAction()`

```
// DOWNLOAD CSV
                echo $out;
                exit;   //die();
```

But still I could not able to find the solution in `jquery post` method, because of time i moved to another solution